# How to sum the values in List<int[]> using Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want to find the sum of the `List<int[]>` using Java 8. Here is my attempt.

```
int sum = counts.stream().flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i).mapToInt(m)).sum();
```

However, I get the error cannot convert to `Stream<Object>` to `<unknown>`.

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview area when entering/editing a post.  Embedded angle brackets MUST be formatted as code (using backticks) or they disappear.

Comment: What do you intend `.mapToInt(m)` to be doing?  What is `m`?

Comment: How about a double for loop?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to `flatMap` to an `IntStream`. After that, taking the sum is easy.

```
int sum = counts.stream()
        .flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 16):

```
int sum = counts.stream().flatMapToInt(array -> IntStream.of(array)).sum();
```

Comment: or `flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)` using method reference, and `Arrays.stream()`, since that is what `IntStream.of()` calls internally.

Comment: Yep, or IntStream::of. I find the lambda slightly clearer for newbies, though.

Comment: Would taking the sum of an int[] directly be more efficient (as you are doing here)?  It seems like your code is a little more verbose but has less autoboxing to Integer.

Comment: @markspace I see no auto boxing there at all.  An `IntStream` is not a `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: @markspace I don't understand what you mean. Which code are you comparing this answer to?

Comment: Well Eran's answer seems to have some autoboxing.  I may have mis-read the others though; AJNeufeld spotted my mistake.

Comment: Thank you. It'd be nice if one could accept all the solutions, by preference!

Answer (score 7):

Your `i` is a primitive array (`int[]`), so `Stream.of(i)` will return a `Stream<int[]>`.

I suggest you first calculate the sum of each individual array and then sum all of them:

```
int sum=counts.stream()
              .mapToInt(ar->IntStream.of(ar).sum()) // convert each int[] to the sum 
                                                    // of that array and transform the
                                                    // Stream to an IntStream
              .sum(); // calculate the total sum
```

Comment: No need for two map calls: `counts.stream().mapToInt(ar -> IntStream.of(ar).sum()).sum()`

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the time to explain 'The how'

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way:

```
int sum = counts.stream()                               // getting Stream<int[]>
                .mapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a).sum())  // getting an IntStream with the sum of every int[]
                .sum();                                 // getting the total sum of all values.
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
int sum = counts.stream().mapToInt(i -> Arrays.stream(i).sum()).sum();
```